# android recyclerview viewholder Multiple Mediaplayer Button change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, media-player

Play and pause working fine but old position icon not change .. playing position icon changing good. I need update notifyDataSetChanged() ?? how can i use it in Holder?

```
   static class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    String AUDIO_URL;
    public MovieHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        audioplay =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audioplay);
        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        audioplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaplayer.reset();
                    mediaplayer.stop();
                    audioplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

                } else {

                    try {

                        mediaplayer.setDataSource(AUDIO_URL);
                        mediaplayer.prepare();
                        mediaplayer.start();
                        audioplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        audioplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        mediaplayer.reset();
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: you must store position of imageview when click and when you clicked on other imageview you must previous position imageview

Comment: store position of onclick of view and update ui of that position inevery click

Comment: Any code? update ui? how can notifyDataSetChanged() not possible pass inside view holder